# Working with JDateTime gives me an exception

Tags: scala, jodatime

```
val funcTimeDiffernceInSeconds = (startTime: String, endTime: String) => {

    println("starttime is"+startTime+"endtime"+endTime)

    if (startTime.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+") && endTime.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+")) {
      //val start = new JDateTime(startTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")

      val start = new JDateTime("2016-02-21 00:17:43:126", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")

      val end = new JDateTime(endTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")
      new Period(start, end).getSeconds().toString()
    }
    else
      "Invalid"
  }
```

This gives me an exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "02-2100"

I am using JDateTime 2.9.4 using this sbt: `( "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.4")`

Comment: On which line? What are the method parameter values?

Comment: On the line..val start = new JDateTime("2016-02-21 00:17:43:126", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")..regardless of parameters..

Answer (score 0):

With this in sbt.build:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.4"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.joda/joda-convert
libraryDependencies += "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1"
```

This would work (making minimal changes to your code):

```
import org.joda.time.Duration
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

val funcTimeDiffernceInSeconds = (startTime: String, endTime: String) => {

  //println("starttime is "+startTime+"\nendtime "+endTime)

  if (startTime.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+") && endTime.matches("[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}[\\s]{1}[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]{2}:[\\d]+")) {
    //val start = new JDateTime(startTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")

    val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")

    val start = formatter.parseDateTime(startTime)

    val end = formatter.parseDateTime(endTime)

    new Duration(start, end).getStandardSeconds.toString
  }
  else
    "Invalid"

}
```

Usage:

```
funcTimeDiffernceInSeconds("2016-02-21 00:17:43:126", "2016-02-22 00:17:43:126")
res0: String = 86400
```